# how to store & retrieve arraylist of objects in file?

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Serialize an ArrayLIst in java without getting errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943197/how-to-serialize-an-arraylist-in-java-without-getting-errors)

I have two arraylists in two different classes. One is to store transaction objects `temporarily` & other for `permanent`. Im using a `addAll` method to copy objects from `temporary` arraylist to `permanent`. And then save objects from `permanent` arraylist to a `file`. When my program restarts, object in `permanent` arraylists are restored from the `file`. But Iam getting an exception. Whats wrong with my code ?

> import java.io.FileInputStream; import java.io.FileOutputStream;
>   import java.io.ObjectInputStream; import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
>   import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> /**  *  * @author Haleemdeen  */ public class FileImportExport {
>
> ```
> private ArrayList<Stock> permntTransactions=new ArrayList<Stock>();
>
>
> void cancatToPerrmntTransactions(ArrayList<Stock> arraylist1){
>     permntTransactions.addAll(arraylist1);
> }
>
> ArrayList<Stock> displayPermntTransactions(){
>     return permntTransactions;
> }
>
>     void exportToFile(){
>
>     try{  // Catch errors in I/O if necessary.
>     // Open a file to write to, named SavedObj.sav.
>     FileOutputStream saveFile=new FileOutputStream("SaveObj.sav");
>
>     // Create an ObjectOutputStream to put objects into save file.
>     ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);
>
>     // Now we do the save.
>     save.writeObject(permntTransactions);
>
>     // Close the file.
>     save.close(); // This also closes saveFile.
>     }
>     catch(Exception exc){
>     exc.printStackTrace(); // If there was an error, print the info.
>     }
> }
>
>         void importFromFile(){
>
>     try{
>     // Open file to read from, named SavedObj.sav.
>     FileInputStream saveFile = new FileInputStream("SaveObj.sav");
>
>     // Create an ObjectInputStream to get objects from save file.
>     ObjectInputStream save = new ObjectInputStream(saveFile);
>
>     // Now we do the restore.
>     // readObject() returns a generic Object, we cast those back
>     // into their original class type.
>
>     permntTransactions = (ArrayList<Stock>) save.readObject();
>
>     // Close the file.
>     save.close(); // This also closes saveFile.
>     }
>     catch(Exception exc){
>     exc.printStackTrace(); // If there was an error, print the info.
>     }
>
>     // Print the values, to see that they've been recovered.
>     System.out.println("\t\t" + permntTransactions);
>     System.out.println();
> } }
> ```

In main method :

> ```
> FileImportExport file1=new FileImportExport();
> file1.cancatToPerrmntTransactions(transactions);
> file1.exportToFile();
> ```

This is what I get as exception:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: m_media_cdstore.Stock
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:570)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)

Comment: Just make the type implement Serializable interface that you want to serialize.. to the highest level of depth of all the included types..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to Serialize Object, make sure The particular Class (`Stock`.java) must implement the `java.io.Serializable` and if Stock class has any other classes those must implement `java.io.Serializable`

Answer (score 5):

The class you want to serialize (`Stock`, in this case) has to implement the [Serializable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: @haleem - assuming you're a beginner to serialization, it's probably a good idea to read a bit about serialization before they jump in (to avoid shooting yourself in the foot later).  e.g. http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-are-the-precautions-for-implementing-serializable/53

Answer (score 3):

The `Stock` class must implement Serializable, and all its fields (to full depth) must either implement Serializable or be primitive.